# How to merge/append PDFs with iTextsharp in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, pdf, itext

I have seen a few ways to do this in C# but the syntax differences are giving me a hard time.  Could someone please help me out just with a PowerShell way of doing this.

What I am trying to accomplish is this:
I have a large PDF that has customer accounting statements.  Each customer has a different amount of pages for their statement.  I am parsing the text on the PDF to find their account number (I have this done).  So I create a PDF with that first page, then it checks to see if there are any more pages for that account number.  If there are, then it will (this is where I need the help) take that page and append it to the first page I have created until there are no more pages with that account number.  So in the end I will have pdf files with the account numbers as filenames and the appropriate pages in each PDF.

I am stuck on the appending pages after the first one is created.

Thank you very much!
Mark

Comment: Please post the code you're having trouble with. Without sample code it's difficult to help you.

Comment: That's the problem.  I don't know the itext syntax of what I want to do to create the code.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the hard part done already as stated, parsing the text to find the page number of the account numbers, here's a working example that shows how to append pages from your large PDF that has customer accounting statements:

```
$workingDirectory = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path;
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom(
    [System.IO.Path]::Combine($workingDirectory, 'itextsharp.dll')
);

$output = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($workingDirectory, 'output.pdf');
$statements = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($workingDirectory, 'statements.pdf');
$fileStream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($output, [System.IO.FileMode]::OpenOrCreate);
$document = New-Object iTextSharp.text.Document;
$pdfCopy = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy($document, $fileStream);
$reader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader($statements);
$document.Open();
$pageCount = $reader.NumberOfPages;
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $pageCount; $i++) {
    if ($i % 2 -eq 0) {
        $pdfCopy.AddPage(
            $pdfCopy.GetImportedPage($reader, $i + 1)
                                             # ^^^^^
                                             # your page number here
        );                                                                                               
    }
}
$pdfCopy.FreeReader($reader);
$reader.Dispose();
$document.Dispose();
$fileStream.Dispose();
```

Add a separate loop to create copies for each individual account number.

Comment: When I get back to work I will check this out and post any questions or updates.  Thank you!

Comment: I just tried this out.  It overwrites the PDF, it doesn't append pages to it.  What am I missing?  What I did is just tried out your code as is.  It creates the output.pdf.  Once that is created if I run it again, it should append pages to that output.pdf.  However it just overwrites it.  Can we please have it append pages to a current PDF that is a file already?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly answer what I was originally trying to do.  However I was able to accomplish what I needed to for this task.  I would still like to know how to append a page to an existing PDF.

```
Add-Type -Path D:\FlavinHOA\itext\itextsharp.dll
$saveDir = 'D:\FlavinHOA\accountid'
$pageSpread = 0
function Copy-PDFPages {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$pdfFile,
        [int]$StartPage,
        [int]$EndPage
    )
    echo $pdfFile
    $inputPdf = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader $pdfFile
    $PageCount = $inputPdf.NumberOfPages
    if ($EndPage -lt $StartPage -or $EndPage -gt $PageCount) {
        $EndPage = $PageCount
    }

    $inputDoc = New-Object `
        iTextSharp.text.Document $inputPdf.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1)

    $fs = New-Object System.IO.FileStream `
        ("$saveDir\$accountID.pdf", "Create")

    $outputWriter = [iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter]::GetInstance($inputDoc ,$fs)

    $inputDoc.Open()
    $cb1 = $outputWriter.DirectContent

    ForEach($targetPage in ($StartPage..$EndPage)) {
        [void]$inputDoc.SetPageSize($inputPdf.GetPageSizeWithRotation($targetPage))
        [void]$inputDoc.NewPage()
        $page = $outputWriter.GetImportedPage($inputPdf, $targetPage);
        $rotation = $inputPdf.GetPageRotation($targetPage)

        if ($rotation -eq 90 -or $rotation -eq 270) {
            $cb1.AddTemplate($page, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, $inputPdf.GetPageSizeWithRotation($targetPage).Height)
        } else {
            $cb1.AddTemplate($page, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
        }
    }

    $inputDoc.Close()

    $fs.Close()
}


function Get-CustomerPages {
    param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory)]
            [string]$pdfFile
        )

$reader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfreader -ArgumentList $pdfFile  
    $count = 0      

        for ($page = 1; $page -le $reader.NumberOfPages; $page++)
        {
            #$page = 48
            $nextPage = $page + 1
            $strategy = new-object  'iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy'
            $strategy2 = new-object  'iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy'            
            $currentText = [iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor]::GetTextFromPage($reader, $page, $strategy);

            if ( $page -lt $reader.NumberOfPages ){
                $nextPageText = [iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor]::GetTextFromPage($reader, $nextPage, $strategy2);
            } else {
                $nextPageText = 'Customer'
            }

            $currentCustMatch = [regex]::Matches($currentText, 'Customer.*')
            $currentCustID = ($currentCustMatch.Value).Replace('Customer Account ID: ','')

            $nextPageMatch = [regex]::Matches($nextPageText, 'Customer.*')
            $nextPageCustID = ($nextPageMatch.Value).Replace('Customer Account ID: ','')

            $accountID = $currentCustID
            $nextAccountID = $nextPageCustID


            if ( $nextAccountID -eq $accountID) {
                echo "More than 1"
                $pageSpread++
            } else {
               echo "-----------Start Export-------------"
               $startExportPage = $page - $pageSpread
               echo "Account ID fed into CopyPDF $accountID"
               echo "Pages exported from $startExportPage to $page"
               Copy-PDFPages -pdfFile $pdfFile -StartPage $startExportPage -EndPage $page
               echo "------------End Export--------------"
               $pageSpread = 0
            }

            $accountID
            $count++
        }
        $Reader.Close();
        $count
}
```